# What permissions are required for a domain user to login to a domain machine?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, credentials

I have been under the impression that Domain Users should be able to login to a domain joined machine with their domain credentials out of the box and no special permissions needed. I'm running this whole setup in Hyper-V so not sure if that makes any difference:
*Two DCs running 2012 R2 Standard
Two Win 8.1 clients*

When I try to login to the domain PC, I get a login issue that the user has to be a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.

Is that required? Are domain users not by default allowed to login to domain PCs like that? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Right-click the VM in Hyper-V Manager and launch the VM Console rather than connect using RDP - that is the equivalent of logging on locally

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I'm not using RDP to connect. I connect to the 8.1 PC through the Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: Yes, but the manager usually let's you connect *either* by RDP or Console, you need to use the console option, otherwise you are in using RDP (Hyper-V Manager just launches a remote desktop session for you)

Comment: I have no other options of connection except Connect. Nothing mentioning RDP or Console.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is due to Enhanced Session Mode being enabled. When so, I'm pretty sure that the Virtual Machine Connection console uses RDP to connect to the VM, which requires the connecting user to be a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group, the local Administrators group or to have the appropriate user rights and RDP protocol permissions.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I dont know if that was actually it or not because in the mean time I just assigned the users to the Remote Desktop Users group but was signing in was hit and miss.

I just disabled the Enhanced Session Mode and they all logged in normally. Going to remove that group membership and test further.

Comment: If you disable Enhanced Session mode and remove the user from the group (reboot the VM) and you don't get the prompt then I suspect I'm right. Let us know what you find.

Comment: @joeqwerty - That looks like it was it. All Remote Desktop User memberships removed, client VMs rebooted and I can login with no issue as long as the Enhanced Session Mode is disabled.

I don't know if you want to submit an answer and I mark it but it seems that I'm all good now. Thank you!

Comment: Answer submitted. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is due to Enhanced Session Mode being enabled. When so, I'm pretty sure that the Virtual Machine Connection console uses RDP to connect to the VM, which requires the connecting user to be a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group, the local Administrators group or to have the appropriate user rights and RDP protocol permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a non-administor user, you need to be authorized to use the service.

Run gpedit.msc
Browse to Computer Configuration -> Windows settings -> Security Settings -> Local policies -> User Rights Assignment
Edit "Allow log on through terminal services"
Run gpupdate /force

Answer (score 0):

Non-Admins aren't allowed to RDP into servers without being a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.  I don't remember if that applies to desktop OS machines or not.

I'm not sure if logging into the machines through the Hyper-V console counts as RDP or not though.

Comment: I'm not trying to login to a server with a domain user. I have a Win 8.1 VM that I'm connecting to and trying to login through and thats where I receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been under the impression that Domain Users should be able to login to a domain joined machine with their domain credentials out of the box and no special permissions needed.

This is correct, but only for the *physical machine*.

> When I try to login to the domain PC, I get a login issue that the user has to be a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.

Remote Desktop logins are different. If you want to login via remote desktop, that has to be set up specially.